# Python convention name files encoding from iso-8859-5 to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

I have about 3500 files whose name is encoded in 'iso-8859-5' and the contents too.
here's how it looks on the Linux console and the 7 zip program:
[image]

I'm trying to write a script that converts to 'UTF-8'

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
#Exemple
#                   how it should look like
#iso-8859-5     ==> utf-8
#НјБ_ФШРУ_Г99   ==> ЭМС_диаг_У99

path = r"C://Users//Kamel//Desktop//работа//macros"
obj = os.scandir(path)

for entry in obj:
    if entry.is_dir() or entry.is_file():
        command = entry.name
        print(command, end="\t\t")
        file_name = command.encode('iso-8859-5').decode('UTF-8')
        print(command)
```

I get this error

```
C:\Python\Python310\python.exe D:/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/ansi_to_utf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\ansi_to_utf.py", line 15, in <module>
    file_name = command.encode('iso-8859-5').decode('UTF-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 11: invalid start byte
BE_BEF      BE_BEF
BE_BEF_IMP_0        BE_BEF_IMP_0
BE_BEF_IMP_1        BE_BEF_IMP_1
BE_BEF_IMP_6        BE_BEF_IMP_6
BE_BEF_IMP_7        BE_BEF_IMP_7
BE_BEF_IMP_8        BE_BEF_IMP_8
BE_BEF_IMP_K        BE_BEF_IMP_K
BE_BEF_IMP_T        BE_BEF_IMP_T
BE_BEF_IMP_В        
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your `command` should already be in Unicode, no need to `encode` it.

Comment: With `command.encode('iso-8859-5').decode('UTF-8')` you try to encode the string `command` to a binary representation in ISO-8859-5 and then you take this binary data and try to decode it with UTF-8. I don't think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Your example `НјБ_ФШРУ_Г99 ==> ЭМС_диаг_У99` could be accomplished as:

```
'НјБ_ФШРУ_Г99'.encode('cp1251').decode('iso-8859-5')
# 'ЭМС_диаг_У99'
```

or (alternatively) as

```
'НјБ_ФШРУ_Г99'.encode('ptcp154').decode('iso-8859-5')
# 'ЭМС_диаг_У99'
```

Your failing example (*… can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 11*):

```
'BE_BEF_IMP_В'.encode('iso-8859-5')
# b'BE_BEF_IMP_\xb2'
```

is solved using the same mechanism:

```
'BE_BEF_IMP_В'.encode('cp1251').decode('iso-8859-5')
# 'BE_BEF_IMP_Т'
```

Comment: it helped a lot thanks